# Преобразование типов для примитивов

Tags: javascript

Читаю про преобразование типов в JavaScript. Не поняла, что происходит в следующих случаях:

```
alert(5 && 2); // 2
alert(2 && 5); // 5
alert(5 || 0); // 5
```

Я сначала думала, что будет преобразование к логическому типу и далее операции уже с преобразованными данными. Но нет. Другой вариант - логическая операция операция работает как побитовая, но тоже что-то не то.

Подскажите, что конкретно происходит в этих примерах?

Comment: @Grundy, ну ты и вопрос выбрал... Там же принятый ответ - жесть. Может, наоборот закроем?

Comment: @Qwertiy, принятый да, странный выбор, но там еще два ответа с пояснениями

Comment: @Grundy, ну так может сюда переписать ответ, а тот закрыть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я сначала думала, что будет преобразование к логическому типу и далее операции уже с преобразованными данными. Но нет.

На самом деле да. Сравнение операндов действительно производится только после приведения их к логическому типу. Вот только *возвращается* не `true` или `false`, а непосредственно один из операндов.

[Вот, что написано](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/index.html#sec-binary-logical-operators) в спецификации по этому поводу:

> The value produced by a && or || operator is not necessarily of type Boolean. The value produced will always be the value of one of the two operand expressions.

В [секции 12.13.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/index.html#sec-binary-logical-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) приведены непосредственно сами алгоритмы (о них еще более подробно ниже) работы этих операторов (`||` и `&&`), из которых видно, что операнды действительно преобразуются к `boolean` типу.

Здесь основная сложность может возникнуть с самим приведением, однако в последней редакции спецификации появилась очень удобная [табличка](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/index.html#table-10), в которой в человеко-понятной форме расписано, какие значения к чему приводятся. Советую ознакомиться, если есть необходимость.

### Возвращаемое значение

Здесь не все так очевидно. Хотя алгоритмы, приводимые спецификацией и являются исчерпывающими, думаю, их разъяснение здесь будет нелишним.

**Оператор `&&`**
Если левый операнд преобразуется к `false`, то он и возвращается. В противном случае возвращается правый операнд:

```js
// Везде вернется левый операнд, поскольку он преобразуется к `false`.
// И даже если и правый операнд тоже преобразуется к false, то все равно будет возвращен левый (случаи 4-6).
let examples = [0 && true, false && "string", "" && 82, 0 && false, false && "", "" && 0];

examples.forEach((example) => {
  console.log(example);
});
```

**Оператор `||`**

Здесь левый операнд всегда будет возвращен наоборот только в том случае, если он приводится к `true`:

```js
// Если левый операнд приводится к true, то он же и возвращается.
// И даже если и правый операнд тоже приводится к true, то все равно возвращается левый (случаи 3 и 4).
// Однако если ни один из них не приводится к true, то возвращается последний (правый) (случаи 5 и 6).
let examples = [true || false, "string" || "", true || true, 1 || [], false || 0, 0 || ""];

examples.forEach((example) => {
  console.log(example);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Согласно [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B):

> `expr1 && expr2` возвращает значение `expr1`, если оно может быть преобразовано в false; иначе возвращает значение `expr2`

Так как в первом примере  `expr1` (`5`) преобразуется к true, то возвращается `expr2` (`2`). Аналогично со вторым примером

> `expr1 || expr2` возвращает значение `expr1`, если оно может быть преобразовано в true; иначе возвращает значение `expr2`

В третьем примере `expr1` (`5`) преобразуется к true, поэтому оно и возвращается