# Оператор && c объектами

Tags: javascript

Друзья, вопрос вот в чем:

```
console.log({a:"a"} && {b:"b"}); // {b:"b"}
```

почему оператор "&&" с объектами дает в результате объект и почему второй?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/892310/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 0):

в данном случае `&&` работает как `if`

learn.javascript.ru -> Логические операторы-> [Оператор И](https://learn.javascript.ru/logical-ops#%D0%B8)

Comment: Спасибо @qwabra. А где можно про это глянуть?

Comment: Спасибо @Igor. Уже увидел

Comment: @Андрей, отредактировал ответ